# Jquery - Append to ID

Tags: jquery

Do to an IE6 bug I need to alter some Jquery,

I want to take an element called `#nav,` append to the `ID`.

I already use `addClass` to create `<div id="#nav" class="test">`

```
$('span .breadcrumb').each(function(){
    $('#Nav').addClass($(this).text());
```

Which takes the breadcrumb navigation text and adds it as a new class to the

Can i use `.append` to add the text to the ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append adds to the content of the element, not its attributes. To do what you're after, I'd use the following:

```
$('#nav').attr('id', 'nav' + 'appendedString');
```

Answer (score 4):

Just change the id attribute:

```
$('#nav').attr('id','nav' + appendString);
```

Where `appendString` contains whatever you want to append.

Comment: And I'm assuming that the HTML is really <div id="nav" class="test"> - without an invalid leading # on the id.

Answer (score 2):

It should work.

```
$(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + $(this).text() );
```

Or whatever you need to do.

Comment: I initially thought this would be the way to go. However, the OP already knows the ID of the element, so there's no need to get the ID again.

Comment: This is a more general answer that will apply in more situations.